# Dart ! operator after a future

Tags: dart

What is the `!` operator after `_cachedValueFuture`?

```dart
  Future<T> fetch(Future<T> Function() callback) async {
    if (_cachedStreamSplitter != null) {
      throw StateError('Previously used to cache via `fetchStream`');
    }
    if (_cachedValueFuture == null) {
      _cachedValueFuture = callback();
      await _cachedValueFuture;
      _startStaleTimer();
    }
    return _cachedValueFuture!;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ["(not-)null assertion operator"](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) which becomes part of Dart with the Null Safety feature in the next release.

The `_cachedValueFuture` variable has type `Future<T>?`, which means a future or null. The `!` operator throws if the value is `null`, so the type of `_cachedValueFuture!` is `Future<T>` which is the required return type of the function.